# batch - moving folders incorrectly by first folder letter

Tags: batch-processing, directory

This command have problems because it eliminate folders when moving folders and not reorder directories by first folder letter perfectly. 
I don't know why. Look [HERE](http://peterlongx.altervista.org/Flash/Richieste/reorder_folder_by_first_letter.htm)

This is incorrect command

```
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%i in (*) do (
  set first=%%i
  move "%%i" "!first:~0,1!"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move documentation says:

> If you are moving only one file, you can also include a filename if you want to rename the file when you move it.

So I think the other directories are renamed rather than moved. Try specifying the full path:

```
move "%%i" "!first:~0,1!"\"%%i"
```

I think this will fail, because the directory `a` doesn't exist then, so you should create it first. The full script should become something like this. Untested, but it should at least give you a clue what is currently wrong, and you can probably fix it from there.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%i in (*) do (
  set first=%%I
  if not exist "!first:~0,1!"\nul md "!first:~0,1!"
  move "%%i" "!first:~0,1!"\"%%i"
)
```

Comment: yes, you're right, it move only if i create folders first. But I want automatically create A,B,C first letter folders because I couldn't have some letters in my collection. I try your command but it  move folders inside a folder called ***%*** folder simply and not move them reordering by first folder letter as i request.